# Why my WebRole runs on WaWebHost instead of IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure

Why is my application being hosted on WaWebHost.exe instead of IIS?

is there a configuration where you can define to run on IIS instead of WaWebHost?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a Sites tag in your ServiceDefinition file.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433080.aspx.